# Is pip.conf broken? extra-index-url ignored

Tags: python, pip

I'm running `pip 24.0` on Ubuntu and have the following in `~/.pip/pip.conf`:

```
[user]                                                                           
extra-index-url https://<MY_TOKEN_NAME>:<MY_TOKEN>@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<MY_PROJECT>/packages/pypi/simple
trusted-host = gitlab.com
```

No other config files exist since `pip config debug` gives me:

```
global:
  /etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu/pip/pip.conf, exists: False
  /etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf, exists: False
  /etc/pip.conf, exists: False
site:
  /usr/pip.conf, exists: False
user:
  /home/timo/.pip/pip.conf, exists: True
    user.extra-index-url https: //...
    user.trusted-host: gitlab.com
  /home/timo/.config/pip/pip.conf, exists: False
```

And `pip config list` correctly displays `user.extra-index-url` and `user.trusted-host`. But now when I run `pip install --user <MY PACKAGE> -vv` I get:

```
1 location(s) to search for versions of <MY PACKAGE>:
* https://pypi.org/simple/<MY PACKAGE>/
```

And my package is not found. When I pass `--extra-index-url` to `pip` directly it works as expected. I'm almost certain that this used to work in the past. Am I crazy or is this fundamental feature broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you confuse user config and `[user]` section. Change `[user]` to `[global]` or `[install]`.

See the docs at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/

*Upd*. BTW, you miss `=` after `extra-index-url`:

```
extra-index-url = https://<MY_TOKEN_NAME>:<MY_TOKEN>@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<MY_PROJECT>/packages/pypi/simple`
```

Comment: That sounds reasonable but neither of these changes anything with respect to my problem.

Comment: Also you miss `=` after `extra-index-url`. I think it's required (unlike command line which is interpreted by a different parser).

Comment: You are right, adding that and changing to `[global]` fixes it. I think I was confusing because `pip config debug` made it seem like everything was in order.